# Magento2: How to move header-bottom to top

Tags: magento2, layout, template

I am trying to move the header to the  top of the page.

I'm use in `default.xml`

```
<move element="header-bottom" destination="header-top" as="new_alias" before="header-middle"/>
```

But without a result:

https://zabezcen.pl/

@update

```
[user@s1 public_html]$ rm -rf pub/static/*
[user@s1 public_html]$ php bin/magento cache:clean
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
customer_notification
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
config_webservice
translate
[user@s1 public_html]$
```

default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Sm\Market\Block\Template" name="config.theme.setting"
                   template="Magento_Theme::html/config.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header.content" template="html/header.phtml"
                   before="page.top">
                <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe.popup" as="form.subscribe.popup"
                       before="-" template="subscribe-popup.phtml" ifconfig="market/advanced/show_newsletter_popup"/>

                <container name="toplinks-header" label="Header Links" as="toplinks-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="toplinks-wrapper"/>

                           <move element="header-bottom" destination="header-top" as="new_alias" before="header-middle"/>

                <container name="navigation-header" label="Navigation" as="navigation-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="navigation-wrapper"/>

                <container name="navigation-header-megamenu" label="Megamenu" as="navigation-header-megamenu"
                           htmlTag="div" htmlClass="navigation-megamenu-wrapper">
                    <block class="Sm\MegaMenu\Block\MegaMenu\View" name="megamenu.topnav" as="megamenu_topnav"
                           template="Sm_MegaMenu::megamenu.phtml"/>
                </container>

                <container name="toplinks-header" label="Header Links" as="toplinks-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="toplinks-wrapper">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>

                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo_theme">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">142</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">42</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="horizontal-css"
                       template="html/horizontal-css.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>

                <container name="navigation.mobile">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="nav.mobile" template="html/nav-mobile.phtml"/>
                </container>

                <container name="compare-header-link" label="Compare Header" as="compare-header-link" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="compare-header-wrapper"/>

                <container name="language-header" label="Language" as="language-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="language-wrapper"/>
                <container name="currency-header" label="Currency" as="currency-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="currency-wrapper"/>
                <container name="logo-header" label="Search" as="logo-header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="logo-wrapper"/>

                <container name="search-header" label="Search" as="search-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="search-wrapper">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch"
                           template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"/>
                </container>

                <container name="search-header-pro" label="Search" as="search-header-pro" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="search-wrapper">
                    <block class="Sm\SearchBox\Block\SearchBox" name="searchbox" as="searchbox"
                           template="Sm_SearchBox::searchbox.form.mini.phtml"/>
                </container>

                <container name="cart-header" label="Mini Cart" as="cart-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="cart-wrapper"/>

                <container name="slideshow-header" label="Slideshow Header" as="slideshow-header" htmlTag="div"
                           htmlClass="slideshow-wrapper"/>

            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="myaccount-link"
                   before="wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/myaccount-link.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="checkout-link"
                   before="authorization-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/checkout-link.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true"/>

        <move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="compare-header-link"/>
        <!-- <move element="logo" destination="logo-header" before="-"/> -->
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="navigation-header"/>
        <move element="store.settings.currency" destination="currency-header"/>
        <move element="store.settings.language" destination="language-header"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="cart-header"/>

        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product-sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product-sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer footer-wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer.content" template="html/footer.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe.footer"
                           as="form.subscribe.footer" before="-" template="subscribe-footer.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
<referenceBlock name="toplinks-header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="logo-header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="language-header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="currency-header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="cart-header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="logo_theme" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the content from `pub/static/*` except from `.htaccess` file.

From command line (navigate to magento root):

`rm -rf pub/static/`

Also, run:

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

This should regenerate the static files and refresh your cache.

Comment: I did as you said, unfortunately this block still sits in this place. I update my topic and also default.xml file

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Bare, yes thank you. I changed header-20 and delete section and everything is okay :)  We try to resolve last issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252841/magento2-how-to-put-logo-in-other-location?noredirect=1#comment356279_252841

Comment: See my answer on this question. I hope it helped :)