# Magento2: How to put logo in other location

Tags: magento2, layout, header

I want to put logo here:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is code header:

```
   <?php $welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome(); ?>
<div class="header-container header-style-20">


    <div class="header-bottom">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme'); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 sidebar-megamenu">
                    <div class="megamenu-content-sidebar">
                        <div class="btn-megamenu">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="<?php echo __('All Categories') ?>"><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu-ver-content">
                            <?php
                            if ($_config->getGeneral('menu_style') == 'megamenu') {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header-megamenu');
                            } else {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header');
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation-mobile-container">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation.mobile'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 searchbox-header">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('search-header-pro'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is code for logo:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 logo-header">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme'); ?>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .header-middle {
        padding: 36px 0 29px;

        .logo-header {
            .logo-wrapper {
                .logo-content {
                    margin: 0;

                    strong {
                        a {
                            img {
                                vertical-align: top;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now when I put code logo after `<div class="header-bottom">`

the logo is displayed but not in one line.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

---

@update

Changed:

1)
`<h1 class="logo-content">` to  `<a class="logo-content">`in file logo.phtml

2)

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme'); ?> <!-- move here -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 sidebar-megamenu">
```

3)

and now is little best - but it's still not in one line

**solved**

Comment: move your logo block to header panel block... <move element="logo" destination="header.panel" before="-" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the logo into the container row. In addition, I can see that the logo is wrapped in `h1` tag which adds a margin at the bottom of it. I would remove it from the logo element. Or change a bit of CSS for it:

```
.logo-wrapper > h1 {
    margin-bottom: auto; /* if not try adding !important to it */
}
```

Also, the search bar seems to be a bit long if you want to add logo next to it. Change the class of the searchbar from `col-lg-9` to `col-lg-7`

```
 <?php $welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome(); ?>
<div class="header-container header-style-20">


    <div class="header-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme'); ?> <!-- move here -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 sidebar-megamenu">
                    <div class="megamenu-content-sidebar">
                        <div class="btn-megamenu">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="<?php echo __('All Categories') ?>"><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu-ver-content">
                            <?php
                            if ($_config->getGeneral('menu_style') == 'megamenu') {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header-megamenu');
                            } else {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header');
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation-mobile-container">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation.mobile'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 searchbox-header"> <!-- change the class here -->
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('search-header-pro'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternative to the class change, you change the classes `flex` property to make the searchbox fit. Try this CSS:

```
.header-bottom .col-lg-9 {
    flex: 0 0 61%; /* might need the !important tag too */
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Bare I added update to my topic

Comment: Ok perfect. This is the result that I wanted to get!

Comment: Glad it helped :) pozdrawiam ;)